# Why do people clear the screen multiple times when using a calculator?

Tags: buttons, psychology, physical

I've noticed that most people when using a real or a virtual calculator, they hit the Clear button multiple times when clearing the screen (even though hitting it once is enough), so I started wondering: is there a flaw in the calculator's design that compels most people to do that?

What makes them trust the button less than the other buttons? Is there some sort of feedback mechanism that's missing? Even if it's just a habit, how does one end up developing it?

Comment: I usually do this with Ctrl-C (copy to clipboard) a lot.  Sort of, I really, really, really want this copied.

Comment: @LarsTech I do that too, but usually because the program/hardware I am using at the time has 'skipped' copies before. Whether due to bugs, slowness, or rogue neutrinos, I could not say!

Comment: It's an interesting habit, maybe it needs a name like Clearing Anxiety or Copy Anxiety :)

Comment: this is the same as pushing the button multiple times to cross a pedestrian zebra

Comment: @LarsTech: IMO that behavior (I do it too) is caused by bad interface design, where hitting a key combo doesn't produce any visual feedback. On Mac OS X, for example, the menu corresponding to the key combo flashes briefly when you hit the key combo.

Comment: probably the same reason people hit the **ESC** in Vi/Vim multiple times to make really sure they are not in insert mode anymore.

Comment: @bizso09 The pedestrian crossing button is a [placebo](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/5456/examples-of-placebo-buttons-in-ui-design)

Comment: The same happens with the ATM

Comment: This reminders of of Right Click on Desktop and select Refresh :) (applies to Windows users)

Comment: @Patrick McElhaney: How did you arrive at that conclusion? It may have been true at one stage, but traffic control has evolved and I can assure you there are now many traffic lights where the light won't change **unless** I press the button. And remember: try this at a time when there is no other traffic, as traffic going in a direction which frees up the one you want may change your light as well.

Comment: @MarjanVenema Okay, *some* of the buttons are placebos. http://www.nytimes.com/2004/02/27/nyregion/27BUTT.html My intent was more to point out an interesting fact than to counter bizso09's claim.  (BTW, in Charlotte, NC, where I live, there are a bunch of new ones that as far as I can tell don't do anything.)

Comment: For the same reason that people push the elevator/lift button multiple times. Oh, wait, that's because elevators are pneumatically controlled and each press of the button pushes a little more air through the tubes which makes it move

Comment: I do it with Ctrl-S.  Even when it's a mouse-click Save button.  I've seen many others do this too.

Comment: @Lars - my keyboard at work does not always handle the ctrl-c so I have to click several times unless I have word running which gives visual feedback

Comment: Once to clear the calculator screen, and a few more times to clear your mind :)

Comment: @LarsTech: ["This is a very random problem that exists in Windows since always. I normally hit Ctrl-C a couple of times when I want to be sure that the copy is really done. Otherwise, once out of about a dozen copy operation misses out."](http://superuser.com/questions/353113)

Comment: I find myself doing this with F5 too to refresh a webpage...

Comment: I think this article answers this question the best: [Why calculators need a better user interface](http://uxmovement.com/thinking/why-calculators-need-a-better-user-interface/). It also provides solutions to other calculator problems that are worth mentioning.

Comment: Thats a very good question. I do the same . !

Comment: My reasons ( my calculators had really rubbery and stiff buttons ) pressing once often didn't reset it. Esp, when you're not paying attention. Usually when im resetting i'm moving away my attention to something else. And to be sure it do get cleared i press it multiple times. Now it's just a habit that confirms i am onto next step to my brain. Short: History with bad calculators.

Comment: Also, i do this with lot of other things...when i want to make my intention clear. To them and to myself and don't care about anything until ive done this. For example in language i'd say "no no noooo ok" or computer power off button, or opening app in mobile by multiple consecutive touching.

Comment: @PatrickMcElhaney Where i live in the NE, there are only functional buttons for crosswalks.  The ones that always switch with the light never even have buttons installed.  Those are prett much only in the downtown area with heavy pedestrian traffic.  All other ped cross signals in the city won't ever activate without pushing the button.

Comment: `CTRL` + `X` has a visual result while `CTRL` + `C` doesn't, which sometimes fails because of the keyboard being bad or not pressing the keys correctly.

Answer (score 517):

(Older) pocket calculators sometimes have several “cancel” buttons (C, CE, etc.) Typically, the CE button would only clear the last entry but not interrupt the current computation. For example, if you press 10 + 1 CE, you would see a 0, but the calculator still expects a second operand for the addition (i.e. it still has "10 +" in memory). Often, there would be no obvious indication of the current state of the calculator (i.e. is it reset and waiting for a new operation or in the middle of one?) If you want to start anew without having to remember which button is which or how a specific calculator works, you can simply press a couple of times on all cancel buttons and that's an habit many people kept from that time.

[image: Windows calculator]

Comment: That's a pretty good explanation for those who have used such calculators, but many people (like me) haven't, yet they still have this habit. How can that happen?

Comment: Yes, that CE / C button duality always drive me crazy, I newer know which one to push. So I push both and to be sure, push them several times :-)

Comment: Many new calculators, particularly desktop 10-key calculators have this operating mode so I don't think it is really an issue of old calculators vs new calculators.

Comment: <ding>Ah, *that's* what the CE button is for...</ding>

Comment: @Mashhoor The behaviour pressing the clear button multiple times may be some kind of social inductance. I mean; most likely the behaviour has been transferred from users who had CE on their calculators over to users who haven't. Meaning you saw someone do it, and that's why you do it yourself (the same learning process for observing traffic and doing the same while you drive a car).

Comment: Yeah I do this. Still have no idea, I even click multiple times on software calculators.

Comment: The first calculators I used had a combination "CE/C" button; press it once to clear your last entry, press again to fully clear. I press C twice out of habit.

Comment: +1. I even find myself pressing the shortcut keys for both of those buttons on the (older) Windows calculator: <kbd>Del</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd>

Comment: To make it more confusing on calculators in the UK "CE" stands for "Clear Everything". That messed up my sums more than a few times.

Comment: It's like with vi and pushing esc several times :)

Comment: I had no idea what you were saying, and then I saw the freehand circle. It makes much more sense now! +1

Comment: It's probably for the same reason people shake polaroids. That actually interferes with the picture clarity. But it made sense back in the Land camera days when you peeled wet layers apart and wanted to dry the photo. It's a cultural appendix.

Comment: While this is a wonderfully colorful explanation, I'm certainly not convinced this is more convincing than other explanations given here. This reminds me of how [false etymology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_etymology) forms. Good stories get +1 votes, better explanations aren't always as compelling. :)

Comment: @Mashhoor, it's for the same reasons people shake polaroids: it was once to dry off the photo paper when you peeled the photo apart, but since then is useless gesture.

Comment: In Australia most calculators were labelled "CE" and "AC" for _Clear Entry_ and _All Clear_ respectively.

Comment: You must upvote this comment if you never press CE, and always restart your entire calculation any time you make an entry mistake.

Comment: Interesting choice of number to display...

Comment: The C/CE duality has gotten me so confused throughout my life that to this day I turn the calculator off and on again. To make sure. i'm capable of removing the batteries, out of sheer paranoia

Answer (score 393):

Other answerers have provided great logical reasons for how these habits could come about, but I think it is simpler than that (plus, how often are any of us logical?).

Calculators obviously have a state, since they do multi-step operations, but they **don't clearly show their state**. In many calculators, if you see a zero on the screen, you have no idea if the calculator is in the middle of an operation or not. So we press Reset a bunch to make sure.

Plus, many of us have gotten burned by starting a new calculation while the calculator was still in another mode, and gotten a totally unpredicted result. So we press reset a bunch to be sure.

Some calculators are better at this. For example the Win7 calc shows you prior operands. Some smartphone calcs show operands in vertical lines, and clear the screen when you press reset. Perhaps an even better enhancement would be to show the background screen in white if the calculator is truly reset, and colored if it's in the middle of something.

But there will always be the tendency to push the button a bunch of times, because better safe than sorry! ;)

Comment: I pressed the upvote button several times.

Comment: @Patrick, odd or even number of times??

Comment: @tomas http://meta.ux.stackexchange.com/q/382/4508

Comment: This is exactly why I hit Ctrl-C 5 times every time I try to copy but I only hit Ctrl-X once when I want to cut.

Comment: Similar reason why people like to push elevator buttons multiple times, It goes faster :)

Comment: I agree with the psychology of this answer the most.  It is like the physical process of cleaning: we sweep back-and-forth with a cloth, broom, etc. many times in order to ensure we 'did not miss anything' that our eye cannot or did not see!

Comment: Not only calculator. Here are common 'useless repetitive' habits I found around my office : refresh windows screen (F5), double click a hyperlink, copy (ctrl+c), Hung up phone using "flash" button, or pushing the button where the phone handle rest (don't know what this button called), refreshing a web page in a (very) slow network. It's a matter of habit and imitating people.

Comment: @PatrickMcElhaney You'd just be alternating the state!

Answer (score 95):

On some old calculators, the clear button had double duty:

- push **once** for **clear-entry**
- push **twice** for **clear-all**

I think this meant that people tended to press clear a few times, to ensure that everything was cleared. It is possible that three clicks would clear the memory as well.

This is one of those habits that people acquired early on in the use of technology, which has continued despite the change in the technology.

And it is an interesting UX question, because the reality that clicking it multiple times has no additional effect does not change the perception. There are other cases of this, I am sure, but we actually just need to understand that this will happen.

Edit:

There is also the sense of clicking and clicking while I make the decision to move onto something else. It is not then based on habit, but just an attempt to reflect what is going on internally, that I need to clear my mind before I move on.

Comment: Maybe if I press the door close button 50 more times this elevator will go faster...

Comment: Schroedingers:
But I've never used any calculator like that (that reqiores multiple clicks to clear), yet i still developed it. Same thing applies to everyone I've asked about this after reading your reply. Also some young people developed this, which is really strange.

Ben:
lol yea people do that as well, but maybe out of frustration?

Comment: Oh I also forgot to add that I saw my young niece the calculator, and when she presses the Clear button, she presses it really hard then continue using the calculator. This mistrust is strange.

Comment: But you may have picked it up from others. But there is that sense that we need to be absolutely sure.

Comment: +1 Yes, this.  Not the fact that there are two clear buttons (C and CE), but that on many older calculators pressing C once cleared the current entry (CE), and pressing it twice cleared the entire calculation.  I still have this muscle memory, and still press the C key twice, just because I don't want to have to think about it.

Comment: Wow, I've been using windows calculator for years and _never noticed_ that "clear all" and "clear entry" were separate buttons. Note that the iPhone's built in calculator _does_ exhibit this 2 presses to "clear all" behavior, so perhaps more of us have used this type of calculator than we realize?

Comment: This. The cheap four-function calculators with a combined C/CE key are what I grew up with in the early 90s.

Comment: A once-is-good, twice-is-better feature is contagious to the brain.  My Mercury Sable car key fob **unlock** button operates like this: push once to unlock the driver's door, push twice to unlock all four doors plus the trunk.  I routinely hit it twice whenever I want to unlock anything.  I also push the unlock button inside the car 3-7 times (bugs the crap out of my kids) whenever I want to unlock something, even though it doesn't even have that feature, and once is always enough.  Thinking also of some lab rat pleasure-lever experiment gone wrong.  (Wrong for the rat, great for science.)

Comment: @BenBrocka If I keep jamming on the pedestrian crossing button, the lights will surely turn red faster.

Comment: `It is possible that three clicks would clear the memory as well.` - Correct.  Some calculators had a couple of M buttons (like `M+`, `M`, and `MC`) that allowed you to save the result of an equation (`M+`, add to memory) and, for example, use it as the divisor in the next equation.  `MC` would clear the remembered value and nothing else, but so would `C / CE` if the entry and equation were already cleared - so, 3 taps to clear all 3 levels

Comment: For what it's worth, I can't recall ever using a physical calculator that didn't require two presses to clear all, but clearly some do exist. I suppose from a UX perspective it'd be better to have two distinct buttons so that users don;t unintentionally clear all when they only wanted to clear the last entry. Either that, or offr some sort of 'undo' button to undo whatever the last action was.

Answer (score 41):

Since there is no negative outcome to hitting the button multiple times, the question becomes really more of, "why wouldn't you hit it more than once?"

It would only take using a calculator with this behavior one time to create this behavior.

Think of it this way....

A person who has never used a calculator that works this way, one day uses a calculator that does.  After some initial frustration, he learns that to clear he must hit the button twice.

He continues the rest of that day.  Every time he hits the button only once his calculations are messed up (negative feedback) every time he hits it twice his calculation are correct (positive feedback)

The next day he uses a calculator that doesn't do this.  However the behavior is already learned.  But now whether he hits the button once or twice doesn't matter: both give positive feedback.  Since both give positive feedback there is nothing to promote unlearning the behavior.

Now we continue on days or weeks later, he uses different calculators but doesn't really differentiate them.  Hitting the button becomes like touch typing, a simple learned response.

When I type I don't think of the letters that I type or even how I move my fingers as I type.  I just think of the words and brain an my fingers know how to make the letter appear on the screen.  When I hit clear on a calculator I don't think "find the clear button, press the button x number of times" ... no I think "clear" and my fingers press clear (however many times they do.)

Now here is the really interesting bit.  Say after awhile he does stop hitting the button twice.  Ok well no problem on his normal calculator. However every time he picks up one of those other calculators, he's going to get negative feedback and the double tap behavior will again be reinforced.

Since he doesn't really differentiate these calculators when he picks them up, eventually his brain will determine that the cost in terms of effort of not hitting the button every time is greater than hitting the button unnecessarily. So... he just presses the button twice all the time.

Comment: "Since there is no negative outcome to hitting the button multiple times, the question becomes really more of, why wouldn't you hit it more than once." Just thinking to myself all the other things that might apply to, for example: Turning a door knob twice to make sure it's locked. With that sort of logic, why stop at two times, I mean maybe the second turn unlocked the door, right?

Comment: @blunders  Yep all sorts of things, but you might be thinking of it a bit wrong.  I'm talking about an instance of positive or neutral feedback with no negative feedback. Actually your example of a door that unlocks when your turn it the second time is a good example of what I'm talking about. The behavior of the door is a great example of negative feedback. 1st time locks the door, 2nd time unlocks it.. therefore don't turn it a 2nd time if it want it locked. I do ~try~ to set my deadbolt twice but it doesn't turn the 2nd time, now if it gave me an electrical shock the 2nd time...

Comment: My point is that some people are obsessive–compulsive, and no matter how much feedback they get, they'll almost insanely attempt to see if something different happens a second time around. This is not an interface malfunction, it's a user malfunction.

Comment: @JustinOhms You're very correct! The way this happened to me (and I would guess, many) is that one of my first pocket calculators had really crappy buttons and would often need a firm, long press to ensure it worked. The failure of a number or operation key to work produced immediate and obvious feed back, but the clear key failing is just as you described in your answer. +1

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obsessive%E2%80%93compulsive_disorder

Answer (score 31):

I'm going to departure a bit from the current line of thought. Back in the typewritter days, I remember seeing my dad's accountant typing really fast on the machine. Whenever he paused for any reason, he kept pushing the "shift" button several times in a row.

He knew pressing that key didn't do anything, and that was exactly the reason he pushed that key... it didn't do anything but kept his fingers busy, or gave the impression that he was busy, or simply because it helped him to keep that rhythm, who knows...

My claim is that some people will press the CE several times just because they know it won't do anything, and that's it.

Comment: On my typewriter, shift *did* do something, namely remove the caps-lock if it was activated. So it could be the same issue: to make sure the typewriter is in "normal" mode, a shift "is always good". Same as hitting Esc before any operation in vim, instead of looking at the (rather poor) mode feedback.

Comment: This is an excellent observation, I sometimes also hit on the table or something when I'm concentrated at something and don't want to lose the line of thought.

Comment: giraff, I understand the functional use of the shift, but in my observation, the accountant (in fact I've seen the same behavior in other people as well) would type shift in rapid continuous succession for about 2 or 3 seconds while he was checking what he had just typed. It almost seemed like he didn't want "to turn the engine off"

Comment: Similar to Starcraft players who are pressing things just to keep fingers occupied and blood flowing etc: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/21647/whats-with-all-the-clicking-the-pros-do-in-the-opening-minutes-of-starcraft-game

Comment: I thought I was the only one. I frequently get to see the "Do you want to turn on Sticky Keys?" dialog because of this habit.

Comment: I think he hit the Shift key in the typewriter to prevent it from starting the screen saver or from getting the screen (pardon, the paper) blank.

Comment: Nice one… I don't think that it has to do something with pushing clear (I myself push it for some other reasons), but it's a great example on how people are keeping themselves in the Flow (a busy, entranced state of mind, described by Csikszentmihalyi)

Answer (score 27):

It is **low-cost fidgety action** (on user's part) **combined** with a device that offers **low levels of feedback** for that action. Such a combination makes you want to repeat that affirmative action.

I find myself using ctrl-c multiple times for the same piece of text. I would do that much less often if MS Word's clipboard manager were open or I had a sys-tray app that blinks every time I use ctrl-c.

As another example, I face conversations where I am disinterested and the other too enthusiastic. He may repeat certain phrases ("job security", "future", "career") to compensate for my disinterestedness. But if I repeat that phrase in front of him, I find that he moves on.

Test for my hypothesis: would a user repeatedly press that button if it gave a satisfying click, or the screen blinked once?

Comment: +1 Good point view. However these "low-cost fidgety action" have a name: compulsions, and they're **not** necessarily symptom of a disorder. And to answer your last question, sometimes yes, sometimes no. I've seen a friend of mine martyring my poor Casio even if it blinked after clicking the clear button... And I've seen myself clicking Ctrl-X more than once when cutting files in MS Windows, where they become 'translucent' (so there's a feedback)

Comment: Another example of low-cost fidgety action is a crosswalk button. I've seen people hit that button ten times in rapid succession. I'm not sure if they were getting their anger out or just wanted to be 9x sure that the button was pressed

Answer (score 20):

Slow feedback can cause this. It makes the user feel like the button is broken and needs to be pressed again or harder, which would work in the real world.

```
Did it work? Did it really work? Really?
```

...also, just general frustration. We're used to some button-presses being idempotent (as with an elevator): once pressed, additional presses are a no-op, so if people are bored and waiting (think: crosswalk buttons), or annoyed with the interface, they may hit it a bunch of times.

Repeated presses may also be used for emphasis--"Clear, dammit!"--or for efficacy--in conversation, we're used to having to work very hard to 'erase' a previous statement.

Finally, a button press takes less time than it takes for the user's mind to switch tasks, so while the mind is switching, just keep pressing 'clear' to keep the hands busy. Otherwise you're gaping at a blank screen and forget what you were doing.

Answer (score 14):

These people, I have to admit myself included, have had experiences before with calculators that if they hit clear or 'C', and do a math expression, the result is incorrect.  So in their mind, they hit the clear button several times to "totally clear" the contents before proceeding.

Have you also noticed that they will hit the 'C' and 'CE' buttons over and over again, not just 'C'?  They are not sure which one does which, so they just slam on both of them until they feel satisfied.

Comment: Agreed, sometimes I've clicked them in the past just to make sure I've cleared the memory contents.

Answer (score 11):

Some of the credit-card sized, solar-powered calculators (without a battery backup), which were all the rage in the early 1990s, didn't always reset to the initial state *completely* when under a low-light condition, after pushing the C (clear all) button, and thus would behave unpredictably after such "incomplete reset" - I think some of the registers were not cleared due to very low power provided by the small solar panel. For this reason, it was customary to press the button multiple times - which prevented the problem.

Also, some models of the calculators had the buttons combined into one: CE/C - first push would erase the last entry, second would reset to initial state.

[image: here].

Comment: The C/CE issue is already mentioned in [this answer](http://ux.stackexchange.com/a/11772/60)

Comment: @ChrisF: True. However, I haven't seen the physical reset issue mentioned in any other answer.

Comment: My understanding is that while calculators are made of of latches which are each supposed to be either "high" or "low", reducing the voltage on a latch just the "right" amount before reapplying power may leave it in an intermediate state.  Latches which are in such states may draw more current than latches which are cleanly high and low, and this current draw may "drag down" the supply voltage below the level required for reliable operation.  Pushing reset once will kick any latches that were not cleanly high or low, and ...

Comment: ...will allow the supply voltage to rebound within a half-second or so, but the fact that the voltage was low when the button was pushed may cause the calculator to have not reset cleanly.  A second push after the voltage has rebounded would resolve things.  Given that many people have sometimes used calculators with a CE/C button, pushing twice as a matter of habit is easily explainable as either occasionally-necessary behavior, or a consequence of seeing others do it.

Answer (score 9):

Note that on simple calculators, both C and CE shows a zero after hitting it. For users who do not frequently use the calculator, it is counter-intuitive to "manually" recall what is the previous state. It is also often unclear which one is the previous state so these users end up having to start all over again. So pressing C and CE is both ensuring that the calculator really is starting from zero and for the user to take a deep sigh!

For users who frequently use calculators and are familiar with the C and CE buttons, or who knows the feature really well, it is more likely that they will only hit the button once. I would not imagine them hittin the CE more than once, but if they do it on the C button, they are probably not thinking of clearing the calculator but rather a fidgety action while they are deep in thought thinking about what to key in for the next calculation.

Answer (score 9):

I'm going to answer this question with another question: **why do people press the elevator button multiple times**, some even if a light indicator turns on immediately after the first time? You see this often with old people. I think the answer is psychological.

Most people by now are pretty accustomed to the way electronics and digital circuitry works: things are usually either on or off. Pressing the button elevator multiple times won't make it  come faster, resetting the calculated multiple times won't make it reset "harder". Still, this model of interaction with hardware relies on an assumptions that things *work as expected*. I believe most of us still have a lot of analog habits, though, and in the analog world you sometimes have to apply yourself a bit more to get stuff to work. We know that sometimes you have to jiggle a key so the lock works and sometimes you have to hit the fan so it stops making a noise.

It doesn't necessarily mean that things have to malfunction for us to give them an "analog" treatment. Sometimes we perceive things as just a bit more complicated than we'd like them to be, and in the trade-off between not being sure whether the elevator's button has registered the signal (which makes us feel worried about waiting like idiots for something that's not coming) and between just one more push of a button, the latter is often the more cost-effective choice.

So, to summarize, even digital things sometimes work in unexpected ways (due to malfunction or hidden complexity) and when faced with this uncertainty many people fall back to their analog habits of giving HW an extra nudge to make sure it knows what they want from it.

Answer (score 8):

Though mono-causal thinking is often for questions like this and makes for the good reading, **there are multiple reasons why people do this and the primary reason may vary from person to person.**

The user is probably aware (judging from the feedback here at least) that the action is not necessary or useful, but they feel compelled to do so regardless due to a number of physiological or psychological compulsions such as brought on by a combination of the following:

Stress, Nervousness, Habit, and the desire to fidget; not helped by stimulants (caffeine mainly I hope)

Also consider: When people press clear, it is just before they type in another calculation so they are in thought and thus not paying particular attention to what their fingers are doing, exacerbating these effects.

Comment: It's quite possible that there are multiple reasons for this behavior but the ones you mention do not seem to explain anything at all. They would just as well apply to pressing any other key or manipulating any other object, yet the question is why do people (seem to) do it more often in this particular situation?

Answer (score 6):

It's a deep instinct that something is more assuredly "done" if the act of doing it is repeated. Why does a dog make little circles before it lays down? Why do people hit the crosswalk button over and over and over when deep down they know that it won't make the light change any faster?

We do receive positive feedback in many such cases. For example the more times I hammer a nail the more sure I can be that it's driven all the way in. The more times I chew a bite of food the less likely I am to choke on it and the easier my digestion will be. There are countless other examples of 'assurance of completion by repetition'. People are simply doing something that comes quite naturally to them: generalizing their experiences and applying them to new experiences. And as previous posters have noted, there is no negative feedback; there is no reason to *not* press the button repeatedly.

In the case of people who push the crosswalk button again and again, I usually attempt to *be* the negative feedback by poking fun at the irrational behavior. Your calculator, if you so chose, could do the same sort of thing. A single click would simply silently clear. A second click would produce a popup stating, "Yes. We have officially cleared the calculator now. One click will suffice. Thank you." People will be annoyed at the popup which will require another click to get rid of, and they will soon learn to click only once. Either that or they'll learn to use a less snarky calculator. ;-)

Comment: I would smash that snarky calculator into a thousand pieces, for the record.

Answer (score 6):

There are probably a few explanations.

1. It is an action that is **easy to perform** and with **little consequences**.
2. Many calculators do not give sufficient **feedback**. Imagine if when the data was cleared you got a mechanical thunk. Would you feel the need to do that again?
3. In a similar vein, calculator keys are **easily stuck**. Therefore it could be a learned behaviour based on past experience.
4. The habit can be **learned** through exposure to other's habits (This might explain why some people do it but not why it originated)

And 2 reasons that are a bit more speculative:

1. It can sometimes be performed at a moment of **anxiety**. The 'oh damn' that's not right moment.
2. In some cases it could be a form of **fidgeting**. A physical movement to project action (or intent) to others. A bit like a routine that signified your engagement with the calculator but giving you time to think about what you are doing (like some people use 'um' in conversations). Signalling that these users are **thinking** about what they need to do.

Answer (score 5):

The repetitive punching of the clear button is really caused by the user not knowing the difference between CE and C. CE clears the current entry, but C clears the entire operation. When most people punch the clear button multiple times, it means they want to clear the entire operation. But because CE and C both give the same feedback when they hit it, there's no way of knowing if the entire operation is cleared for someone who isn't sure what the difference between the two buttons are. So by pressing it multiple times, the user feels that the entire operation gets cleared, not just the current entry. Here's a great article that offers an innovative solution to the current calculator interface: http://uxmovement.com/thinking/why-calculators-need-a-better-user-interface/

Answer (score 3):

My guess is most people have experienced accidentally re-using the result of the last calculation in the next calculation they're trying to make.

Once I was adding a sequence of numbers and got in the habit of hitting the plus key after each number, THEN looking at the next number. I got distracted, moved on to a new calculation and came back and started entering a new, unrelated number only to discover it was added in to the previous result by mistake.

This got me in the habit of pressing the C button frequently on in-fix calculators.

For what it's worth, I grew up with Hewlett-Packard [RPN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) calculators, and when I use them, I virtually never clear the previous register contents since it's much less likely you'll accidentally use a previous calculation with post fix calculations.

So... I'm going for the "I just want to return the calculator to a known state" explanation.

Answer (score 3):

**Repetition expresses the user's uncertainty as to the system state.** The user is uncertain as to whether Clear eliminates only the current entry, or resets the entire computation.

Calculators, especially one-line skeuomorphic ones, violate the following [usability heuristics](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/ten-usability-heuristics/):

1. Visibility of system status
2. Match between system and the real world

In contrast with handwritten computations and more advanced mathematical software, one-line calculators obscure all but the current numerical input, leading to greater uncertainty. The user's need for certainty is further driven by the tedious cost of "hunt and peck" input.

**Therefore pressing Clear multiple times is a low-cost hedge against an opaque system.**

Answer (score 1):

Most people who do so (I am definitely not one of them, but have seen people doing it), would have had bad experiences at some point in time, for example, the previous numbers being used for the next calculation because the C key didn't clear it up. I've also seen people pressing Ctrl+C or Ctrl+S multiple times, and people even repeatedly right clicking their desktops and pressing refresh (Windows only).

There could be multiple reasons for these habitual actions (most people wouldn't think or even wouldn't know that they do this):

- They realized that these actions didn't work when done only once, there was a possibility of error, and want to be sure.
- These actions do not provide a visual cue or feedback. The calculator screen shows zero even when you press 5 followed by +, or press C. Ctrl+C doesn't show (except in apps like MS Office) that you've copied something. Ctrl+X or Ctrl+V, for instance, show that something has been cut or copied, and the user would repeat these actions only when they know that it didn't work the first time.
- Actions like these are harmless, and make the same changes to the system when done repeatedly. That is also why you'd Ctrl+C thrice but Ctrl+V only once.
- People want to pause to think at times, and their otherwise fast actions do not give them enough time. These key combinations provide them, of course subconscious, gaps to think.

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest explanation and one in which I have no evidence, is our need to be as thorough as possible. We want to make sure something has been done properly. Not everyone will have this compulsion.

A similar example is if I lock my car using the remote fob, I still feel the need to double check the door handles to make sure its locked. I may even walk away from my car only to return and check again! I know, crazy.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple reason:

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> is a double-key combination, so it has higher probability of mistyping. If I am typing at my fastest rate, then this is part of a streaming sequences of stuff I am doing. Pressing it more than once greatly reduces the probability of error, whereas if I had to stop and intentionally considered each <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, this dramatically reduces my typing efficiency.

In other words, while a single, conscious single press is enough. In practice, a single press is not sufficient in practice to statistically produce the low error rate and high efficiency that results from inserting a few extra double presses.

Answer (score 0):

For most of my computational life, I have used a graphing calculator. The significance of that is that I can see where I am and, when entering another calculation, I can consciously decide if I want to keep going or start a new calculation. (By including the Ans variable, usually some 2nd^Enter click.) When I use a regular calculator, I usually just use it for quick calculations. Sometimes I need to start over, and I hit one of the buttons, and sometimes it doesn't actually clear out. Frustrating. I have never had a reason to really understand the difference between C and CE on a calculator because it is just so easy to hit C and CE a couple of times when I use a basic calculator.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer lies in the answer of the following question:

- Why does a guitarist moves his fingers as if plucking imaginary strings when his favorite tune plays in the background?
- Why can't you simultaneously draw a clockwise circle with your foot and a counterclockwise circle with your same-sided hand? [***reference***](https://www.quora.com/Why-cant-you-simultaneously-draw-a-clockwise-circle-with-your-foot-and-a-counterclockwise-circle-with-your-same-sided-hand)

The reason to all these lies in the sub conscious. A guitarist is too used to playing on the guitar, and hence whenever his favorite tune plays, his mind connects it to the time he was strumming his guitar.

Similarly, simultaneous hand and leg movements is deeply stored in your subconscious. You reaffirm this notion everytime you walk. You will not realize this is happening, but your legs and hands move together. A slight change in that motion and suddenly you feel uncomfortable.

Now that we have understood how the subconscious works, lets explain the calculator button.

Whenever you use the calculator, you're either copying an equation form a paper, or calculating expenses that you had thought in your mind. So the user's mind is doing TWO things at the same time;

(1) thinking about the expenses or reading the equation from the paper, and

(2) typing the numbers in the calculator.

Since there are two things, the task that is more trivial and has less possibility of change is transferred to the sub conscious. The sub conscious has the task of pushing buttons on the calculator, and continuous instruction is transferred by the conscious brain.

When we stop, or an equation has finished computing, the conscious brain pivots into thinking about what the answer means, or whether it tallies, or how much savings he has left and what not. During this pivot, the subconscious' last instruction was the clear button, and it continues to press it until the conscious brain tells it to stop or press another button.

A similar thing happens, when you're into deep thought, and you don't know what you're looking at or if someone is calling you, because the subconscious nature of looking or hearing is overpowered by the thought in your head.

Answer (score 0):

A similar habit can also be observed in **Lifts** where people press the CLOSE door button multiple times. The reason is very simple. Since the users don't get any feedback from the system about their action, they tend to ensure that they did it right. In the case of Lifts, they keep on pressing the CLOSE door button until it starts to close.

The similar happens in the case of Calculators. As many people have mentioned, calculator have **C** and **CE**. On pressing CE, users only get a part feedback (in older calculators) which sets screen to 0 which appears to be same as C. But on further calculations, the results appear to be erratic. These errors force the users to press CE multiple times. This behaviour eventually shifts to C because they get confused between the functions. The erratic calculations reinforce their mental model to ensure if everything has been set to 0.