# Should I provide feedback from a save button?

Tags: buttons, feedback, save, windows-os

I'm currently in the process of developing a Windows Application which produces Word Documents.

In the program there is the ability to save your progress (different to the "Save as a Word Document" option). This option "Save Current Progress" saves your progress, there is no user input, except the action of clicking the button (i.e. they don't have to specify a file location).

When designing the functionality for this button I researched other instances of "Save" buttons in programs. Most of them resemble floppy disks, and on clicking them there is **no feedback** (except the subtle visual cue of mouseover and click on the button itself). i.e. there is no alert window saying "you have saved" nor does the button change to signify a saved state.

The problem is that in my application this could be confusing. In Microsoft Word (for instance) it is the most natural thing to click the save icon and *know* it has saved, without any positive feedback. However in my application it confuses users and they say that they "don't know" that what they've done has actually saved anything. The icon is different to the Word one. It resembles a hard drive with an arrow pointing down onto it.

[image]

However, surely the thought process should be the same. I'm going to change the functionality so that the icon changes to that of a tick momentarily to give positive reinforcement that the status has saved, but I'm interested as to why the two scenarios differ so much.

## Update

As per some of the suggestions here I have created this graphic to switch states when the user saves.

[image]

Comment: FYI, Word has visual feedback on saving progress. It's not obvious to occasional user though. Pay attention to the right side of the status bar next time you save.

Comment: Yeah I'm aware of this, but its really subtle. Similarly a lot of code editing programs have the name of the file in the title bar with a star (*) next to it if the file has unsaved changes. The star then disappears when you save. However this is also pretty subtle, and I'm not sure if your "generic computer user" will have the technical knowledge to understand these cues.

Comment: If you are asking if you should provide feedback on the save button, meaning on the button itself, I think that is a different question than the current question title. The pictures in your question indicate you are leaning toward providing feedback on the button and that is what some of the other answers respond to. However, if that is the case, I suggest you change the title of the question to fit.

Comment: Tom, absolutely not. I'm not asking about the actual button itself. What I'm asking (as is clear in the question) is whether the act of "Saving" should be acknowledged at all. It is the prerogative of the answerer how they interpret this, whether it is the case that the feedback should occur on the button itself (which is a nice idea, that's where the user is focussing, and its not intrusive to their experience, as an alert dialogue would be) or whether there is some other feedback to let the user know their action has completed successfully.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

On clicking the save button in almost any application for the first time, you are asked where to save the file. If your application does not do this, it would be understandable that people are unsure as to whether it has worked or not.

My advice would be to grey out the icon and replace the icon with a spinner while the save operation is taking place. Even if saving is near-instantaneous, do it anyway for a minimum of a second or so.

[image]

Once this period is over, replace the icon with a tick, and change the button text to **Save Complete** for a second or so, before reverting back to the normal button. This provides strong visual feedback that the button is doing its job.

[image]

Comment: Tellig them that it is happening, and that it is completed OK ( or not ) but doing this unintrusively is the best option. I think MS are actually wrong to not provide this feedback, but people get used to the way that thing work.

Comment: Thank you. So you're suggesting that the fact that there is **never** any user input makes the button ambiguous? I had never thought about it like that. Just out of interest, why is the interim "Saving" state necessary? Does it reinforce the user's idea that **something** is happening?

Comment: The fact that the icon changes momentarily doesn't necessary mean that the user will be aware the save has occurred. I think the fact the button dramatically changes its visual style between states could be problematic, but if you choose this method I'd recommend keeping the 'save complete' state on screen until the document has been changed (and potentially requires saving again).

Comment: And if there is an issue, the "saving" state may remain on longer, which gives some indication to the user that the app is trying to save, and hasn't just died.

Comment: If you want and need to draw attention to something, an animation or visual change is the best way to do it, our eyes are drawn to motion. Just don't use it in a situation that would get *annoying*

Comment: Based on the opinions here I have since created a new image, a gif with three states. "Save progress" (as above) an interim "Saving" with a rotating circle animation and a "save successful" with a tick. I will attempt to put the finished graphic in my question for reference

Comment: I would suggest that instead of "Save Complete," just return to a grayed-out "Save Progress" button, which then becomes active again once there are any changes that could be saved.

Comment: @fluffy what's the reasoning behind this?

Comment: @ThomasClayson IMO it's less distracting, and it also shows that there is no purpose to attempting to save again. It is a behavior that is well-established by quite a few things; it is at least as old as Emacs and as recent as OSX Lion's "save a version" mechanism.  It also helps to tell more OCD users that there is no need to constantly click the "save" button "just to be sure."

Comment: @fluffy: While "Save Complete" need not be (probably shouldn't be) active, I think it's important to make it clear when the button is disabled because a save is complete.  If the appearance is the same as when a save is in progress, closing the form before the save completes might cause data loss; if the user thinks the button might indicate "save in progress", the user might be afraid to close the window for fear of data loss.

Answer (score 27):

As you've stated, it's important that the user is provided with feedback about the success / failure of the save operation.

One way that some business applications achieve this is by *disabling* the save button when the most recent version of a file has been safely saved to disk.

1. User clicks save.
2. File is saved.
3. Button is dimmed / non-clickable -> this provides a sense of positive reinforcement that the application has performed the operation successfully.

Comment: +1 Having the save button dimmed/non-clickable when there are no unsaved changes in a file is my favourite mechanic.

Comment: This is a useful insight, however I steered away from this in my application as I (and I'm aware others) "enjoy" what I've come to know as the `lift/elevator theory` whereby clicking a button (or pressing the "call lift" button) multiple times somehow reinforces the action (or makes the lift come quicker). Obviously this isn't the case, however it is nice to be in control of the application, rather than the application "locking" certain controls. This was the theory behind not disabling the button.

Comment: I think the lift/elevator/traffic light scenario is interesting - but I think by disabling the button you're potentially countering the problem posed.

Comment: I don't like disabled buttons. I ealise that this is personal preference, but I want to be able to save my documents again, even if nothing has changed. I want that control over what is happening, even though I know it is illusory. Personally, I would only disable buttons when clicking them twice in a row will have unwanted effects ( like, say, sending an email multiple times, or paying for a purchase )

Comment: Fair enough, but I'd argue that being able to save a document twice provides no benefit to the user.  Realising that you're looking at the most up-to-date (saved) version of a document *is* useful, because you know it doesn't need saving.

Comment: I agree with @SchroedingersCat. I find not being able to save very annoying. For example, when I program in Eclipse I sometimes run console commands which changes a file on disk that I currently have open in the editor. Sometimes I just want to resave the file to revert those changes, but since Eclipse thinks I have not done any changes, I can't save the file. So I have to insert a space or something to enable the save button. Very annoying...

Comment: @Svish; that's an interesting case - but arguably the program which has the file open should be aware that the file has been updated and respond accordingly.

Comment: I think it is perfectly reasonable to dim a save button when there is nothing to save, you could even change the tooltip to say "No changes since last save" to reinforce the fact.

Comment: @Thomas [Why do people clear the screen multiple times when using a calculator?](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/11660/why-do-people-clear-the-screen-multiple-times-when-using-a-calculator)

Answer (score 4):

I have to ask why you think this button is necessary. If this is an *incremental* save, of a file that the user is working on, then I would think VIM's method is better. I.E. keep a swap version of the file, and silently save to it every few moments. It doesn't bother the user, they don't need to do it manually, and if there is a crash, all edits are saved.

**However**, this avoids the issue where the user works on a file for a while, and decides to throw away the changes by *not saving*. When your program closes with edits, you can ask the user if they wish to save or not. Also, provide them with a decent method for managing these backup files, if necessary.

Part of the problem is that many, but not all, users know there is two copies of the file in existence. The one on the hard drive, and the one being edited in memory. But most programs just assume that the hard drive copy is the only copy. This disconnect between user expectations and program functionality is partly why your users are confused. See [this post from Joel Spolsky](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/uibook/chapters/fog0000000058.html) for an example.

So there are two competing user models, and your program has an ambiguous input. Not only does it not show **if** it worked, but group A(file only exists on drive) doesn't know why you need it, and group B(file is on drive, and in memory) is annoyed that the program doesn't handle this internally.

Comment: Hmm, an interesting point. I suppose the point here is that a user might come to the program to edit something and might want to "revert" to the original last-saved state of the form. Take the example of Photoshop for instance. You work from a PSD. This is a file which you open in photoshop, edit and save changes to. It doesn't  "auto save" or anything like that. Then you export to jpg (or other). Its not quite the same, but I'm aware that "autosave" might be alarming or confusing for its own reasons.

Comment: @ThomasClayson Yes, autosave can be alarming. Namely, because most versions *overwrite* the current file. You want to save "draft" copy or some such, so that if the user quits without deliberately saving, they go back to the old version. A very large number of people use this as poor man's version control.

Comment: I like this idea, but personally I have an inherent lack of trust in technology.  Being sure that your document is safe provides a very powerful sense of security.  If saving 'just happens' .. perhaps feedback is still necessary?

Comment: @codeinthehole No, no. There is two separate saves going on. You are always able to do a normal save with feedback. But, behind the scenes the program keeps a rolling backup of your current version. If the system crashes, you can restore from the backup *or the original*. I suggest you check out how vim works with it's swap files, tilde files, and undo files. Every time my vim instance has crashed, or I lost my remote connection, I could restore to where I was without data loss.

Comment: @Spencer Rathbun; in that case, I think your solution is an additional feature, rather than an answer to this question.  It's a nice point, but maybe not entirely relevant.  Even incremental saves sometimes need to be explicit.

Comment: Why does Joel Spolsky think that Classic MacOS's application switching model belongs to "Microsoft Excel"?

Comment: @codeinthehole The op said that he went down this path to solve a problem his users were having. I *believe* this is a better solution for the underlying problem he indicated. But, I'm not in his userbase, so he should do some testing and find out what actually solves the problem instead of listening to me pontificate.

Answer (score 2):

There should be an indication of wether or not there are pending changes to save, and a great way to do this is by whether the save button is enabled. After saving successfully, the disable the save button, indicating that saving is not an appropiate action because there is nothing new to save. When the user edits something, then enable the save button, indicating there are unsaved changes.

Indicators that saving is in progress are a good solution to a related but different problem, that saving takes a perceptably long time, so the user should be assured that something is happening.

Comment: I tend to agree, however the "evidence" points to a different conclusion. When I'm in Microsoft Word, or Excel, or any similar programs there is NO indicator (that I have noticed) that I have started editing, and often I will come back to an open Word Document and think to myself "have I saved this yet?". If this is wrong then why has no-one thought to change this in the many iterations of the Office suite? i.e. why don't people approach new software with the preconceptions based on their use of Microsoft products? This is my dialemma

Comment: @ThomasClayson That is rather weak evidence, and that line of thinking leads to information cascades. I have used this approach in my own software, both specifically with save buttons and more generally enabling buttons only when they potentially do something useful, and it works well. Seriously, you should aspire to provide a better user experience than Microsoft. As I recall, Word does have a unsaved changes indicator, but is subtle and unassociated with the save button, making it go unnoticed and therefor useless.

Comment: I agree @JGWeissman, however I'm not targeting you or me with this program - I'm targeting users who use Microsoft Word day in day out. The kind of people who use internet explorer because they don't know that you can get different browsers, and even if they did then they don't know why they should bother changing because "everything works in internet explorer". ;) I need to give the most intuitive platform for my users, and I believe that disabling the button will cause unnecessary confusion. There are other ways I can alert the user to unsaved changes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You should absolutely provide feedback from a save button.

Word does provide feedback from the save button, but you may never notice it in most normal cases. On a long save operation in Word, you will notice a message in the status bar and the user is prevented from making changes during the save operation. Also, if you haven't saved the document and attempt to close it you will be prompted to save. This is another way of providing feedback on the save operation itself.

Here is an example: 
[image: Word is Saving Status]

Comment: How did you manage to get that screenshot? My computer saves too quickly to press Print Screen.

Comment: I inserted a movie into the document before saving it.

Comment: *I inserted a movie into the document before saving it* clever! :) Yeah, I understand you answer but normally this usually happens very quickly and goes largely unnoticed by the "average" user. Contrast this to web apps for instance. If you click save usually you are presented with the same page with a persistant notification (usually in green or yellow) saying "Saved" or "Your email has been sent successfully" or something. The reason for providing the feedback on the button was to lower the intrusion level to make it obvious but not annoying.

Comment: It is subtle, but often it's the smallest details that make the biggest difference between a good experience and a great one. Microsoft has taken a lot of care to study the user experience in Word, so it makes sense to take cues from them for your windows application. The question I might be asking myself in your shoes is why does this make sense in Word, but not my application? Maybe users trust the save operation in Word more. Word is very inviting to new users in general.

Answer (score 0):

I realize you are doing a windows app however things are a changin and you should move toward the UI feedback trends.

For example,

- the new mac apps are automatically saving as you work
- google docs automatically saves while you work
- lots of apps are following suite toward this trend

Since you are building a new app, think in the trends rather than the status quo. Things are evolving toward a better user experience in that regard and you should too if possible, regardless if its in a legacy framework. Windows 8 will be coming out fairly soon so this trend will follow there as well in order to compete.

Comment: I wish I could do this, this would help everyone. However I feel that this could confuse the intended audience of my application more so than just not providing feedback on a button.

Comment: Understood, however @ThomasClayson ask yourself if that's what Google Docs is doing or Apple's UI trend. I imagine you have not used those yet so its harder to visualize what I mean exactly. Try it out a bit. It may not be one-size fits all type of thing but I do appreciate not having to explicitly save things and it becomes second nature in work flow, similar to how scrolling with the mouse pad on a laptop with a flick of your finger has become in grained in so many people after being so used to a mouse grab.

Comment: I always use google docs, and I work on a Mac 100% of the time. However, my intended users work on Windows computers, use Microsoft Word, Microsoft Outlook, click the "Apply" button then the "Ok" button when using the control panel and all sorts. I'm not trying to be cutting edge and modern (unfortunately) I'm trying to make my application useable and accessible. It needs to have an interface that is simple, useable and intuitive. I don't think that auto save (for the demographic I am targeting) is intuitive unfortunately. Maybe in a decade.

Comment: In a decade we won't even be using the web like this. Siri is just a hint of it. I think it will be more toward conversation with visual feedback while you converse freely to a machine with elements of minority report thrown in IMO.