# Help! 'Saving' animation for edits that are saved on change (without clicking a save button)

Tags: save, animation

I can't think of great examples on the net (comparisons to draw, that is). You've seen the feature before though. You are making an edit to something--say, a setting. And when you make the change, there is a quick transparent modal with the 'loading' circle animation (or a flashing disk or something), and the word 'Saving', or something similar. This appears on screen for maybe half a second, one second? Then it goes away, and there is a fade-out box near the saved feature that says 'Saved', or 'Successful', and it fades out over 5 seconds or something...

So, despite sounding like a teenage girl in the explanation (like, totally), have I explained it well enough?

My question here is, what are implementation ideas/examples for this? I'm looking both at user experience patterns/thoughts, and also implementation thoughts.

We're on DOJO framework, so really we can do anything from an animated GIF and CSS transitioned box to something fancy and javascript-y (as long as it's doable within DOJO--I don't want to use jQuery, for example).

Thanks for your contributions!

Comment: We can't really reel off lots of examples of save animations, that's not really what a Q&A site is for. Nor can we suggest explicit DOJO examples - UX as a field is technology-agnostic. However we can help with the question about whether what you currently have is suitable. What are your reservations about doing it the way you have described?

Comment: [This is what I need](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/15798/should-i-provide-feedback-from-a-save-button) Well, thanks to the great associated posts feature here, I was actually able to find what I need in the post above! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Oh! well, I was formulating my suggestions post .. :)
Here's what I drew so-far:

Following are some points that I could think of, for the 'Save Animation':

1. No. of steps that do the 'Save' for each edit
2. Frequency of edits
3. Toggle switch for Autosave feature (required)
4. The type of edit process:

   - Step critical (Each step should be saved)
   - Feature Integrity critical (Entire edit or nothing should be saved)

I found your idea of an Autosave Feature, totaly **awesome**

Apart from a usual preloader for denoting Ajax activity and then displaying a fading out label saying 'Saved', you can also:

- Highlight the record/edit step label with a green color with a smooth transition(fade-in green may be)